# Comparing files under raw folder

Tags: android, media

I have many files in different formats under `raw` folders. I just want to list only `video files`. How can i compare them in **android**.

Any idea or snippet code?

Comment: what about playing with the extension at the end of the file's name.

Comment: i use video files in .3gp format

Comment: so in your folder iterate on all the files, and for every file look if the name ends with .3gp, or if it's contained in a list of supported formats

Comment: try below code it will work....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public void listRaw(){
        Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
        for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
          if(fields[count].getName().toUpperCase().endsWith(".3GP"))
            Log.i("Raw Asset: ", fields[count].getName());
        }
    }
```